# How can I receive more than one character at a time from telnet server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, telnet

I open up CMD and create a telnet connection with:

`telnet localhost 5555`

And the connection will open with the server printing "Welcome" as you can see in the image below

[image]

However, when I type on the telnet window it sends the reply one character at a time rather than in full sentences (e.g. I go to type hello and it sends hello world one character at a time), like this:

serveroutput: h serveroutput: e serveroutput: l serveroutput: l serveroutput: o

I want it to send the full word hello or a full sentence rather than sending one character at a time.

How can I do this?

Here's the code:

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *


host = ''
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(1)

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

    while True:
        print("Waiting for input")
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print("Data: ", data)
        reply = 'Server output: ' + data.decode('utf-8')   
        if not data: 
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that the Telnet sends one char at a time and there isn't much that you can do about this. Either you can use another Telnet clone that allows this or on Python side you can use a buffer and wait for a '\n' character to analize the line.

Comment: I think you should configure your telnet client. However, it won't be a reliable solution because TCP (referenced by `SOCK_STREAM`) does not have a notion of "message" - connection is a stream of bytes, so you cannot reliably "separate" messages, even if both client and server are willing to do that. You can detect newline characters and treat them as message boundary, though.

Comment: I'm confused. You use a telnet client to talk to the program you've shown us? That's important to mention. Its kinda confusing to suggest that you are talking with a regular telnet server when you aren't. Telnet tends to send characters as soon as you type them and telnet servers tend to echo them back immediately because that's how you can see what you are typing. You could change your program to wait until entire lines are received before echoing but then the person on typing on the telnet client wouldn't see what they write.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you need to code the logic for **accumulating data**. Something like:

```
line = ""
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    for c in data:
        if c == ord('\n'):
            print "message: " + line
            line = ""
        else:
            line = line + c
    if not data: 
        break
```

Comment: `\n` is not telnet packet end delimiter. `data = conn.recv(1024)` meaning 1024 byte length, how to compare byte array to char ?

Comment: @dsgdfg thanks, you're right, i did not notice it is python 3.